# Return column location of a value in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have a simple ask: I am trying to return the column title for an inputted value.  Example below

```
Column 1      Column 2       Column 3
  1             7               19
  3             31              33
  4             12              14
```

So if I inputted the value "31", I would like to return "Column 2"

Anyone know how this is done?  Thanks!

Comment: What if "31" was in more than one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula

`=INDEX(1:1,SMALL(IF(A2:C4=31,COLUMN(A2:C4)),1))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If 31 doesn't occur in A2:C4 you'll get an error [#NUM!]

If 31 occurs more than once in that range you'll get the header from the first occurence (i.e. the leftmost column)

Comment: This is giving me a #Value error when I select my range equal to my value (i.e. AE4:EW739=31)  Any ideas why?

Comment: solved it -- wasn't inputting the array in properly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Far from ideal but in say A10 and copied across:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A9,31)=0,"",A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your example, let us say headlines are in row 1 and the values in range A2:C4, the lookup value in D1, then this formula will do it: (for multiple occurences of the lookup value it will take the last fitting column)

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MAX((A2:C4=D1)*COLUMN(A2:C4)))),"None")
```

**IMPORTANT**: You have to make it an array formula. After typing or inserting this formula in the target cell or in the formula bar DON'T just hit 'Return' or leave the cell but hit **CTRL+SHIFT+RETURN**. If you did it right the formula will be surrounded by curly brackets in formula bar. `={IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MAX((A2:C4=D1)*COLUMN(A2:C4)))),"None")}`. Otherwise you get wrong results.

For array formulas also look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).